# how to add chapter name to number and title line in Appendices?

Tags: chapters, titlesec, appendices, naming

Consider test case:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{10pt}{}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test1}
\section{Test1.1}

\begin{appendices}
% I need Appendix added to "chapters" here.
\chapter{Test2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Chapter names were removed using `\titleformat`. But for all chapters in Appendices need to add chapter name to chapter number and title. Mean need to change `A Test2` to `Appendix A Test2`. How to do this?

Comment: By the way, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCqXV.png) when I compile your minimal example - exactly what you want... unless you're referring to the content in the document, not the ToC.

Comment: @Werner absolutely not a duplicate for your link above. mean need changes not for ToC, but for a text, described between `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another `\titleformat` change within the `appendices` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{10pt}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test1}
\section{Test1.1}

\begin{appendices}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{Appendix \thechapter}{10pt}{}
\chapter{Test2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

With an up-to-date LaTeX, you can add

```
\AddToHook{env/appendices/begin}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{Appendix \thechapter}{10pt}{}%
}
```

to your preamble so you don't have to add it mid-document. Environment (and other) hook management has formed part of the LaTeX kernel since Oct 2020. Update your distribution if this doesn't work out-of-the-box (as it should).

Comment: special thanks for a tip with environment hooks. for now doing such things by defining with `\fancypagestyle{}` separate pagestyles for title, ToC, main document, etc., and putting there relevant `\renewcommand`s. but hooks seems to be next level. where is it possible to find full list of LaTeX `env/*` environments? in particular which allow to address document parts like title, ToC, main document, etc. *LaTeX’s hook management* manual doesn't have such

Comment: works as it should, thank you

Comment: @AlexShevchenko: See section **3.1.1 Generic hooks for all environments** of [`lthooks`](//texdoc.net/pkg/lthooks).